# Select all checkboxes using jQuery and select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<select id="deloptions">
<option value="none">Select none</option>
<option value="all">Select all</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to check all theck and uncheck all the checkboxes from a table which is placed after this select. The checkboxes are placed in the 1st collumn of the table. They all have "delme" class. I've tried everything but it doesn't seem to work... Here is my current code:

```
$('#deloptions').change(function(){ 
var value = $(this).val();
if (value == 'all') {
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

I've tried using their class too but no success... like:

```
$('.delme').prop('checked', false);
```

Trying reaching for the table didn't work either... so i'm kindda stucked.

EDITED:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Content</th>
<th>Date Added</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<tr id="37">
<td><input type="checkbox" class="delme" id="37"></td>
<td>Good news!</td>
<td>This is a message!</td>
<td>2013-07-22</td>
<td>Here is a button</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7vxYA/)

Comment: Are there any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Code is fine with table also http://jsfiddle.net/ZKW6U/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#deloptions').change(function(){ 
 var value = $(this).val();
 if (value == 'all') {
   $('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
 } else {
   $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', 'no');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: Got it. The problem was that i've imported an older version of jquery (1.3.0) :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
    $("#deloptions").change(function(){
       if($("#deloptions  option:selected").val()=="all")
       {
              $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
       }
       else
       {
              $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
       }
    });
 })
```

Comment: Got it. The problem was that i've imported an older version of jquery (1.3.0) :D

Answer (score 0):

You may have not added `jQuery` reference as your code is working fine

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/D4Jaf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
$(function(){

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
});
```